# Why This C program gives random string as output,where i have done something wrong

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int i;
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    int ln = strlen(str);

    char str2[ln][ln];
    printf("enter string 2\n");
    for(i=1;i<=ln;i++)
    scanf("%s",str2[i]);
    printf("\n____________\n");
    for(i=ln;i>=1;i--)
    printf("%s ",str2[i]);


}
```

is this program proper or am i missing something in it , it gives wrong output 
.
Input :-  zero
          Mahaveer is my name
expected output :- name is my mahaveer
but output comes :- name mname imanme mimname .

Comment: Why do you think your program would give the expected output? Do you understand the difference between `"%s"` and `"%c"` format specifier in `printf` and how to make array of C-strings?

Comment: The valid indexing values to `str2` range from `0` to `ln - 1`. The code accesses `str2` out of those bounds.

Comment: `scanf("%s",str);` --> `scanf("%99s",str);`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**
You assume `char str2[ln];` is an array of c-strings. But in reality it is array of `char` which can behave as single `C-string`.

**Solution**
 One of the solution is to use 2 dimensional array of `char`s to behave as array of C-string.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to understand why?

Comment: dev c++ force closes when i try to debug it !!

Comment: Are you building in [debug mode](http://eilat.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/cis1_5/HowToDebug.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

In you code:

```
char str2[ln];//this declares an array with size 4 characters, not 4 arrays with dynamic size
printf("enter string 2\n");
for(i=1;i<=ln;i++)//i should start from 0, better way to do, else we will be wasting the 1st byte
scanf("%s",&str2[i]);//%s in scanf expect char array in 2nd parameter, but &str2[i] indicates a character
printf("\n____________\n");
for(i=ln;i>=1;i--)
printf("%s ",&str2[i]);//%s says to print a character array, but the second parameter passed,&str2[i], is a character
```

try this instead, this will meet your requirements:

```
char str2[ln][20];//each sub array with 20 characters size
printf("enter string 2\n");
for(i=0;i<ln;i++)
{
    scanf("%s",str2[i]);
}
printf("\n____________\n");
for(i=ln-1;i>=0;i--)
printf("%s ",str2[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: ya i changed it with 2 dimensional array but what i need to print is the strings in reverse order . Input :- what is your name  Output :- name your is what  without reverse order it works fine with for loop with `for(i=0;i<ln;i++)` but with `for(i=ln;i>1;i--)` it prints something unwanted .

Comment: reverse order in the case each word or characters from last to first?

Comment: I have edited my answer, use: for(i=ln;i>=0;i--) instead of for(i=0;i<ln;i++)

Comment: ya reverse order , last words comes at first place ,2nd last at 2nd place from begining and so on ..check out the image output [link](http://s31.postimg.org/dfo8vs1jv/Untitled.png)

Comment: @Gaurav, yes. I forgot. I have edited. Thanks for correcting me. :-)

Comment: @Mahaveer, it prints the output like you want. I have tested it too.

Comment: thanks buddys .. it worked without "ln-1" all i needed to change is 2dimensional array.

Comment: Yes. But you need to include "ln-1" in order to stop run time error, out of bound error.

Comment: why don't you hit the select answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int i, j;
    char str[100];
    char *words[50], *word;

    printf("Input :- \n");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    strlwr(str);//convert to lowcase

    i = 0;
    word = strtok(str, " \t\n");//split to word
    while(word){
        words[i++] = word;
        word = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }
#if 0
    //swap head and tail
    if(i){
        word = words[i-1];
        words[i-1] = words[0];
        words[0] = word;
    }
    for(j = 0; j < i; ++j){
        if(j)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%s", words[j]);
    }
#else
    //reverse word
    for(j = i-1; j >= 0; --j){
        printf("%s", words[j]);
        if(j)
            putchar(' ');
    }
#endif
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: even this one is not working properly see this [link](http://s31.postimg.org/ukmjvao63/image.png)  and what i want to know is why the program i have posted gives this type of output ??

Comment: @Mahaveer your sample is `Mahaveer is my name` --> `name is my mahaveer`.  Do you hope is to reverse the whole?

Comment: ya i want output as you have written.

Comment: @Mahaveer I update answer. "expected output :- name is my mahaveer" should be modified.